# Plone / Zope / ZEO on SSD - Recommendations

Tags: plone, ssd

I'm evaluating a new server for our Plone / Zope Installation (3.2GB Data.fs and 7.4GB blobstorage). The installation serves mostly authenticated requests and has lots of edits (Intranet and eLearning environment). I'm thinking about running the ZODB (with ZEO) on a RAID1 with two SSD disks to speed up the site and the edits. But the informations I could find on the Internet about SSDs in servers are still quite sparse.

I have a few related questions:

- Is it recommended run ZODB on SSD disks?
- Does anyone have approximate estimations on the performance difference of running on SLC SSD disks compared to a RAID5 array with 5 15k SAS disks?
- Is RAID1 on SSD disks advisable? I'm a bit concerned about the possibility that both disks might fail at the same time.
- Does anyone already run a similar setup in production? What are your experiences with it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/250986-32-raid-super-fast-hard-drive#t1770934) post will help.

I'd say go with spinning disks in RAID for now for production. I'd recommend only using SSDs for sacrificial things, or maybe for read/write cache drives for ZFS.